# How to reset MCP2200 to default settings?

Tags: usb, uart, microchip

I designed a simple USB to UART coverter using  Microchip's MCP2200 microcontroller. worked nicely for a while, but while i was trying to Update configuration using supplied config utility... the application crashed during the cofiguration was beig updated..

Now whenever i connect it to the computer, it says USB device not recognized.(malfunctioned)..

So, my question is, Is there any way to reset default settings by hardware. as it is not recognized by the computer at all.

P.S. i did not changed the VID/PID so it is not a problem of driver.

Comment: I had the same problem, turns out it's only Windows that can't recognize it anymore. Still works like a charm under Linux Mint 17.

Comment: Did you fix the configuration through Linux?

Comment: Did you find out why Windows won't recognize it anymore? Driver signing problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're out of luck on this one. If the configuration memory was erased and the app crashed before the new values were written, it would explain why it's no longer enumerating - the firmware doesn't read valid config data and can't recover.

(Interesting side note: the MCP2200 is a [relabelled PIC18F14K50](http://dangerousprototypes.com/2011/01/18/hack-open-source-usb-stack-on-mcp2200/) with pre-blown firmware inside it. You may be able to salvage it for other uses - the FOSS replacement for the MCP2200 firmware doesn't appear to be ready yet.)

Comment: `MCP2200 is a relabelled PIC18F14K50` That's interesting... Does that mean i can copy firmware from other MCP2200 and upload to this corrupted one?

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesnt seem like you can. According to the website the code is read protected.

Comment: Perhaps you could read the 256-byte EEPROM section and write that to the bricked device? If you can do it without touching program memory it may work...

Comment: @AdamLawrence never mind. i ordered more of those chips.. but i will try to copy EEPROM data from working chip to bricked one once they arrive.